# Docker: Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, debian

I have a Rails application that I want to deploy using Docker on an Ubuntu server. I have the Dockerfile for the application already set up, right now I want to view the `nginx` conf in its container.

I ran the command below to start an `nginx` container in an interactive mode:

```
docker run -i -t nginx:latest /bin/bash
```

Right now I am trying to install `nano` editor in order to view the configuration for `nginx` configuration (`nginx.conf`)  using the commands below:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nano
export TERM=xterm
```

However, when I run the first command `apt-get update`, I get the error below:

```
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                  
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists... Done    
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have checked very well it has nothing to do with network connectivity.

Comment: Edge case (not your issue but I'm including it here): I had the same problem and was running a BIND9 server on the docker host. It allowed LAN resolution (192.168.0.0/24) but containers were connecting from a 172 docker network and so couldn't resolve. Adding 172.0.0.0/8 to the BIND ACL for access solved this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Here's how I solved it**:

Start the docker container for the application in an interactive mode, in my case it an `nginx` container :

```
docker run -i -t nginx:latest /bin/bash
```

Run the command below to grant `read` permission to the `others` role for the `resolv.conf` file:

```
chmod o+r /etc/resolv.conf
```

**Note**: If you are having this issue on your host machine (Ubuntu Linux OS) and not for the Docker containers, then run the same command adding `sudo` to it in the host machine terminal:

```
sudo chmod o+r /etc/resolv.conf
```

Endeavour to exit your bash interactive terminal once you run this:

```
exit
```

And then open a new bash interactive terminal and run the commands again:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nano
export TERM=xterm
```

Everything should work fine now.

Reference to this on Digital Ocean: [Apt error: Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/apt-error-temporary-failure-resolving-deb-debian-org)

That's all.

Comment: The more I run into these kinds of issues the more i dislike docker.

Answer (score 146):

Try restarting Docker.

One of these should work:

```
sudo service docker restart
sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
sudo snap restart docker
```

Even in cases where Docker never worked before, some commenters said this was helpful.

Comment: Usually restarting the service works for me, but sometimes I need to restart my VM to get it working again.

Comment: restarting not solving my problem

Comment: docker service restart worked for me

Comment: Restarting the service didn't do it for me, but restarting the machine did (Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: Restarting with `sudo snap restart docker` fixed it for me on a fresh docker install, so would recommend trying the restart first, since it's so quick and simple, even if it wasn't "fine in the past".

Answer (score 122):

Specifying a DNS server for docker containers helped me.

Create a `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file with this content:

```
{
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
}
```

and restart the docker service:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

src: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#specify-dns-servers-for-docker

Comment: This also made `apt` like 10x faster in my containers!

Comment: Unfortunately this did not resolve the issue for me. I did restart the service.

Comment: boom! Tried everything, this solved the issue for me. No issues when running docker @ home with DSL, but today I'm connecting through my phone's hotspot. This is the only solution that worked for me (ubuntu 22.04, stopping the VPN didn't help).

Comment: Solved it for me on October 2022 ! Thanks a bunch @j-kluseczka!

Comment: Did the trick for me. Using Docker inside WSL2

Comment: restarting did not worked for me. but this solution worked

Comment: work at Aug 2023

Comment: Worked for me as well... I wonder why devs make things so unpleasant.... First time I use docker since today and I really felt like I wanted to uninstall docker... I just hate when devs don't make it easy.

Comment: Worked for me as well on a VPS. Thanks

Answer (score 81):

Perhaps the network on the VM is not communicating with the default network created by docker during the build (bridge), so try "host" network :

```
docker build --network host -t [image_name]
```

for docker-compose:

```yaml
service_name:
    container_name: name
    build: 
      context: .
      network: host
```

Comment: solved it for me in September of 2021! Note, I'm not sure it was necessary but I had disconnected from my VPN before running this command.

Comment: Solved for me on 2022 :)

Comment: Solved for me on Aug 2022 :D

Comment: Solved it for me on September 2022 :D

Comment: Solved it for me on October 2022 :D

Comment: Solved it for me in January 2023, Thank you!

Comment: Solved it for me in February 2023 :D

Comment: Solved VPN problems on our side in March 2023 :D

Comment: Solved it for me in April 2023, in a Google Cloud Compute Engine Instance. Thanks!

Comment: Solved it for me in June 2023 =P

Comment: Solved it for me in June 2023

Comment: solved build, broke docker compose container interactions...

Comment: Solved it for me on Nov. 2023

Comment: Solved on Jan. 2024. Thank you!

Comment: Still working in late January 2024!

Answer (score 29):

If you have VPN running, stop it and try again. It solved for me!

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem probably never would have figured it out

Answer (score 10):

Run this command:

**echo -e "nameserver 8.8.8.8\nnameserver 8.8.4.4" |sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf**

After that run-

**sudo apt-get update**

This worked for me.

Comment: head --lines 2 /etc/resolv.conf # -> # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8) #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo vi /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

and check flag of iptables, aslo add DNS if not added

```
{...., "iptables":true,"dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]}
```

then

```
sudo service docker restart
```

solved me

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and in my case it was file access control.

I uses **extended acls** on the docker root folder and did not realize it, because they where inherited from the folder above (stupid idea to test docker in a "scratch" directory where permissions are set via extended acls).

This lead to the situation that "/etc/resolv.conf" had setting "640" inside the running docker container with a "+" marking the extended acls. But the image did not have extended acls installed and could not handle it.

The weird thing was that, as far as I can see, all other network tools worked (e.g. `ping`) but only `apt` could no access the DNS resolver.

After removing the extended acls from the docker root and setting the usual acls, everything worked inside the running container.

Similar to the answer of "Promise Prestion", but solved permanently for new containers, too.

Comment: This was a nightmare to debug, but removing the ACLS from the docker data folder solved my issue. This was also the source of many weird errors like https://askubuntu.com/questions/771936/permission-error-when-installing-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-cant-drop-privileges inside the Docker container

Answer (score 4):

Under Debian, as root, I've ran:

```
/etc/init.d/docker restart
```

This solved the issue for me.

Then build and run the container again.

Answer (score 2):

**I easily resolved it via:**

```
- docker exec -it nginx bash (Go inside container)
- ping google.com (if not working)
- exit (Exit from container)
- sudo service docker restart
```

**Please also confirms /etc/sysctl.conf**

```
- net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

**sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf**

Comment: step two not possible: `bash: ping: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

I was having the wrong DNS IP address in my /etc/docker/daemon.json. In my case, it was my home router DNS IP address and I was trying from the office network.
I found out my office DNS and updated with that.

```
{ 
  "dns": ["192.168.1.1"] 
}
```

Comment: for me, i also added office dns and it worked.  `"dns": ["8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4","192.168.3.1"]`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I tried many suggested solutions, but my issue was gone after I rebooted my VM.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue, under debian.
Root cause was a bad DOCKER-USER rule in iptables chain

Those rules have been haded

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eno1 -j DROP
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -s 90.62.xxx.xx/32 -i eno1 -j ACCEPT
```

so removing temporarily following rule fix the point

```
iptables -D DOCKER-USER -i eno1 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Coming here from some docker cross compiling headache:

While forking some repo I manually downloaded its `root` folder containing `confd` stuff and added it just like the original maintainer did.

```
ADD root /
```

after this I was not able to `apt update` anymore.

I found that the permission of my `root` named folder was wrong. `stat -f "%OLp" root` revealed it is `700`, but must be `755` to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Arch version 6.0.11** and **docker version 20.10.21**, and having this issues inside docker containers.

Thanks to @Marco, that was the initial hint to solve this. The problem is related to the use of **[extended ACLs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Access_Control_Lists)** in the host system.

The docker root folder has ACLs, you can see this as it has a plus sign at the end of permissions **"+"**:

```bash
$ sudo ls -lh /var/lib/docker
drw-rw-r--+    3 root root 4.0K Nov 24  2021 network
```

And what is the problem? Some docker images does not have ACLs installed, so as it was pointed this causes an issue.

Other network tools like curl resolved DNS properly, but `apt` or `git` have problems with DNS resolution.

---

**TLDR; Where is the fix?** Modify ACL to set default rx to others.

```
setfacl -R -d -m o::rx /var/lib/docker
```

After that, all network tools will be able to perform DNS resolution.

Credits:

[Marco comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66802006/2900599)

[Closed git issue in docker](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35722#issuecomment-349778176)

Answer (score 0):

[The answer from @Mario Olivio Flores](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64053785/7520239) suggests using the `service` command. That is correct and probably works currently on all Linux distributions. However, as most Linux distributions prefer `systemd` over systemV, it seems better to use just that with the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

For example, on my Linux distribution the service script located at `/usr/sbin/service` just wraps `systemctl`, see this excerpt:

```
# When this machine is running systemd, standard service calls are turned into
# systemctl calls.
if [ -n "$is_systemd" ]
then
   UNIT="${SERVICE%.sh}.service"

   case "${ACTION}" in
      restart|status|try-restart)
         exec systemctl $sctl_args ${ACTION} ${UNIT}
      ;;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turned out to be a random WSL 2 issue -- running `wsl --shutdown` and restarting the containers solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

It used to work before, then I got the same error. I've had a Debian and a Docker update in the meantime however. And I've found, that the latest Docker on debian/bookworm has this `/etc/docker/daemon.json` config:

```
{
     "bridge": "none"
}
```

Changing `"none"` to `""` followed by the command `systemctl docker restart` solved my problem. Seems like it uses the default bridge that I have had before, you may have to create it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason was the incorrect Docker installation.

To fix it I had to remove the old Docker installation and install `docker.io` which is preferable for `Ubuntu`. Then I was able to build successfully my container.