# Error in Dockerfile + Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile but it gets an error when I want to build it. my Dockerfile is :

```
FROM php:7.4.8-fpm

ENV APP_HOME /var/www/html

# install all the dependencies and enable PHP modules
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y
```

I get the following errors:

```
Err:1 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'httpredir.debian.org'
Err:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'httpredir.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567404/docker-temporary-failure-resolving-deb-debian-org)

Comment: @jakub No unfortunately it does not solve my problem

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567404/docker-temporary-failure-resolving-deb-debian-org