# Unable to build docker file for Jitsi web

Tags: docker, apt, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I'm using docker-jitsi-meet on ubuntu 22.04. However when I attempt to build the  docker image of the web version of jitsi, getting the following error :

````html
Building myapp_webserver
Step 1/15 : ARG JITSI_REPO=jitsi
Step 2/15 : ARG BASE_TAG=stable
Step 3/15 : FROM ${JITSI_REPO}/base:${BASE_TAG}
 ---> 319b2e366502
Step 4/15 : LABEL org.opencontainers.image.title="Jitsi Meet"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c5cc34716be6
Step 5/15 : LABEL org.opencontainers.image.description="WebRTC compatible JavaScript application that uses Jitsi Videobridge to provide high quality, scalable video conferences."
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 298eae2d1ff6
Step 6/15 : LABEL org.opencontainers.image.url="https://jitsi.org/jitsi-meet/"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dfebe0d4db74
Step 7/15 : LABEL org.opencontainers.image.source="https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 20b854afd9af
Step 8/15 : LABEL org.opencontainers.image.documentation="https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0c82729c172f
Step 9/15 : ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/2.8.8/acme.sh /opt

 ---> Using cache
 ---> 494ef2963655
Step 10/15 : COPY rootfs/ /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 06c78e7406c2
Step 11/15 : RUN apt-dpkg-wrap apt-get update &&     apt-dpkg-wrap apt-get install -y cron nginx-extras jitsi-meet-web socat curl jq &&     mv /usr/share/jitsi-meet/interface_config.js /defaults &&     rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf &&     apt-cleanup
 ---> Running in 9b3e147c12de
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:2 http://ftp.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ftp.debian.org'
Err:3 https://download.jitsi.org stable/ InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'download.jitsi.org'
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ftp.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch https://download.jitsi.org/stable/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'download.jitsi.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package cron
E: Unable to locate package nginx-extras
E: Unable to locate package jitsi-meet-web
E: Unable to locate package socat
E: Unable to locate package curl
E: Unable to locate package jq
ERROR: Service 'myapp_webserver' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-dpkg-wrap apt-get update &&     apt-dpkg-wrap apt-get install -y cron nginx-extras jitsi-meet-web socat curl jq &&     mv /usr/share/jitsi-meet/interface_config.js /defaults &&     rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf &&     apt-cleanup' returned a non-zero code: 100```
````

My Docker file :

```html
ARG JITSI_REPO=jitsi
ARG BASE_TAG=stable
FROM ${JITSI_REPO}/base:${BASE_TAG}

LABEL org.opencontainers.image.title="Jitsi Meet"
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.description="WebRTC compatible JavaScript application that uses Jitsi Videobridge to provide high quality, scalable video conferences."
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.url="https://jitsi.org/jitsi-meet/"
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.source="https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet"
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.documentation="https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/"

ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/2.8.8/acme.sh /opt
COPY rootfs/ /

RUN apt-dpkg-wrap apt-get update && \
    apt-dpkg-wrap apt-get install -y cron nginx-extras jitsi-meet-web socat curl jq && \
    mv /usr/share/jitsi-meet/interface_config.js /defaults && \
    rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && \
    apt-cleanup

COPY myapp_web/ /usr/share/jitsi-meet/
COPY myapp_web/interface_config.js /defaults/interface_config.js

EXPOSE 80 443

VOLUME ["/config", "/usr/share/jitsi-meet/transcripts"]
```

My docker-compose.yml(pasting only the relevant code)

```html
services:
    # Frontend
    myapp_webserver:
        container_name: myapp_webserver
        #image: jitsi/web:${JITSI_IMAGE_VERSION:-stable}
        build:
             dockerfile: Dockerfile
             context: ./web
        restart: ${RESTART_POLICY:-unless-stopped}
        ports:
            - '${HTTP_PORT}:80'
            - '${HTTPS_PORT}:443'
        volumes:
            - ${CONFIG}/web:/config:Z
            - ${CONFIG}/web/crontabs:/var/spool/cron/crontabs:Z
            - ${CONFIG}/transcripts:/usr/share/jitsi-meet/transcripts:Z
        environment:
            - AMPLITUDE_ID
            - ANALYTICS_SCRIPT_URLS
            - ANALYTICS_WHITELISTED_EVENTS
            - AUDIO_QUALITY_OPUS_BITRATE
            - AUTO_CAPTION_ON_RECORD
            - BRANDING_DATA_URL
            - CALLSTATS_CUSTOM_SCRIPT_URL
            - CALLSTATS_ID
            - CALLSTATS_SECRET
            - CHROME_EXTENSION_BANNER_JSON
            - CONFCODE_URL
            - CONFIG_EXTERNAL_CONNECT
            - DEFAULT_LANGUAGE
            - DEPLOYMENTINFO_ENVIRONMENT
            - DEPLOYMENTINFO_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE
            - DEPLOYMENTINFO_REGION
            - DEPLOYMENTINFO_SHARD
            - DEPLOYMENTINFO_USERREGION
            - DESKTOP_SHARING_FRAMERATE_MIN
            - DESKTOP_SHARING_FRAMERATE_MAX
            - DIALIN_NUMBERS_URL
            - DIALOUT_AUTH_URL
            - DIALOUT_CODES_URL
            - DISABLE_AUDIO_LEVELS
            - DISABLE_DEEP_LINKING
            - DISABLE_GRANT_MODERATOR
            - DISABLE_HTTPS
            - DISABLE_KICKOUT
            - DISABLE_LOCAL_RECORDING
            - DISABLE_POLLS
            - DISABLE_PRIVATE_CHAT
            - DISABLE_PROFILE
            - DISABLE_REACTIONS
            - DISABLE_REMOTE_VIDEO_MENU
            - DISABLE_START_FOR_ALL
            - DROPBOX_APPKEY
            - DROPBOX_REDIRECT_URI
            - DYNAMIC_BRANDING_URL
            - ENABLE_AUDIO_PROCESSING
            - ENABLE_AUTH
            - ENABLE_BREAKOUT_ROOMS
            - ENABLE_CALENDAR
            - ENABLE_COLIBRI_WEBSOCKET
            - ENABLE_E2EPING
            - ENABLE_FILE_RECORDING_SHARING
            - ENABLE_GUESTS
            - ENABLE_HSTS
            - ENABLE_HTTP_REDIRECT
            - ENABLE_IPV6
            - ENABLE_LETSENCRYPT
            - ENABLE_LIPSYNC
            - ENABLE_NO_AUDIO_DETECTION
            - ENABLE_NOISY_MIC_DETECTION
            - ENABLE_OCTO
            - ENABLE_OPUS_RED
            - ENABLE_PREJOIN_PAGE
            - ENABLE_P2P
            - ENABLE_WELCOME_PAGE
            - ENABLE_CLOSE_PAGE
            - ENABLE_LIVESTREAMING
            - ENABLE_LOCAL_RECORDING_NOTIFY_ALL_PARTICIPANT
            - ENABLE_LOCAL_RECORDING_SELF_START
            - ENABLE_RECORDING
            - ENABLE_REMB
            - ENABLE_REQUIRE_DISPLAY_NAME
            - ENABLE_SERVICE_RECORDING
            - ENABLE_SIMULCAST
            - ENABLE_STATS_ID
            - ENABLE_STEREO
            - ENABLE_SUBDOMAINS
            - ENABLE_TALK_WHILE_MUTED
            - ENABLE_TCC
            - ENABLE_TRANSCRIPTIONS
            - ENABLE_XMPP_WEBSOCKET
            - ENABLE_JAAS_COMPONENTS
            - ETHERPAD_PUBLIC_URL
            - ETHERPAD_URL_BASE
            - E2EPING_NUM_REQUESTS
            - E2EPING_MAX_CONFERENCE_SIZE
            - E2EPING_MAX_MESSAGE_PER_SECOND
            - GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID
            - GOOGLE_API_APP_CLIENT_ID
            - HIDE_PREMEETING_BUTTONS
            - HIDE_PREJOIN_DISPLAY_NAME
            - HIDE_PREJOIN_EXTRA_BUTTONS
            - INVITE_SERVICE_URL
            - LETSENCRYPT_DOMAIN
            - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL
            - LETSENCRYPT_USE_STAGING
            - MATOMO_ENDPOINT
            - MATOMO_SITE_ID
            - MICROSOFT_API_APP_CLIENT_ID
            - NGINX_RESOLVER
            - NGINX_WORKER_PROCESSES
            - NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS
            - PEOPLE_SEARCH_URL
            - PREFERRED_LANGUAGE
            - PUBLIC_URL
            - P2P_PREFERRED_CODEC
            - RESOLUTION
            - RESOLUTION_MIN
            - RESOLUTION_WIDTH
            - RESOLUTION_WIDTH_MIN
            - START_AUDIO_MUTED
            - START_AUDIO_ONLY
            - START_BITRATE
            - START_SILENT
            - START_WITH_AUDIO_MUTED
            - START_VIDEO_MUTED
            - START_WITH_VIDEO_MUTED
            - TESTING_CAP_SCREENSHARE_BITRATE
            - TESTING_OCTO_PROBABILITY
            - TOKEN_AUTH_URL
            - TOOLBAR_BUTTONS
            - TRANSLATION_LANGUAGES
            - TRANSLATION_LANGUAGES_HEAD
            - TZ
            - USE_APP_LANGUAGE
            - VIDEOQUALITY_BITRATE_H264_LOW
            - VIDEOQUALITY_BITRATE_H264_STANDARD
            - VIDEOQUALITY_BITRATE_H264_HIGH
            - VIDEOQUALITY_BITRATE_VP8_LOW
            - VIDEOQUALITY_BITRATE_VP8_STANDARD
            - VIDEOQUALITY_BITRATE_VP8_HIGH
            - VIDEOQUALITY_BITRATE_VP9_LOW
            - VIDEOQUALITY_BITRATE_VP9_STANDARD
            - VIDEOQUALITY_BITRATE_VP9_HIGH
            - VIDEOQUALITY_ENFORCE_PREFERRED_CODEC
            - VIDEOQUALITY_PREFERRED_CODEC
            - XMPP_AUTH_DOMAIN
            - XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE
            - XMPP_DOMAIN
            - XMPP_GUEST_DOMAIN
            - XMPP_MUC_DOMAIN
            - XMPP_RECORDER_DOMAIN
            - XMPP_PORT
            - WHITEBOARD_ENABLED
            - WHITEBOARD_COLLAB_SERVER_PUBLIC_URL
        networks:
            meet.jitsi:

# Custom network so all services can communicate using a FQDN
networks:
    meet.jitsi:
```

The reason I'm using the provided docker file for building a new image is for UI customization. As you can see, I have commented out the image part in docker-compose of myapp_webserver and provided context to use the dockerFile.

I can't seem the understand where the issue is. Help needed.

EDIT: I switched to Linux/Debian bullseye from Ubuntu 22.04 to check whether it is an OS issue.The problem still persists even on Linux. This means either I'm missing something on both Linux and Ubuntu OR it is not a problem of OS but

- the apt-dpkg repository or docker itself.

EDIT :

After debugging for days, I figured the following: The culprit file is this one : 10-config inside rootfs/etc/cont-init.d/10-config
(https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet/tree/master/web/rootfs/etc/cont-init.d)

This is the file that was causing build issues. Once I deleted the file the build completed and containers spawned ,of course with an error that it couldn't find the 10-config file. I can't seem to figure out the reason why it's causing issues since I do not know how it was built. Need some assistance.

This is the file itself. All I know is it is a script that attempts to read from etc/resolv/conf.
Here is the file itself:

```html
#!/usr/bin/with-contenv bash

# make our folders
mkdir -p \
    /config/{nginx/site-confs,keys} \
    /run \
    /var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body \
    /var/tmp/nginx

# generate keys (maybe)
if [[ $DISABLE_HTTPS -ne 1 ]]; then
    if [[ $ENABLE_LETSENCRYPT -eq 1 ]]; then
        mkdir -p /config/acme.sh
        pushd /opt
        sh ./acme.sh --install --home /config/acme.sh --accountemail $LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL
        popd

        STAGING=""
        if [[ $LETSENCRYPT_USE_STAGING -eq 1 ]]; then
            STAGING="--staging"
        fi
        export LE_WORKING_DIR="/config/acme.sh"
        # TODO: move away from standalone mode to webroot mode.
        /config/acme.sh/acme.sh \
            $STAGING \
            --issue \
            --standalone \
            --pre-hook "if [[ -d /var/run/s6/services/nginx ]]; then s6-svc -d /var/run/s6/services/nginx; fi" \
            --post-hook "if [[ -d /var/run/s6/services/nginx ]]; then s6-svc -u /var/run/s6/services/nginx; fi" \
            -d $LETSENCRYPT_DOMAIN
        rc=$?
        if [[ $rc -eq 1 ]]; then
            echo "Failed to obtain a certificate from the Let's Encrypt CA."
            # this tries to get the user's attention and to spare the
            # authority's rate limit:
            sleep 15
            echo "Exiting."
            exit 1
        fi
        if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]]; then
            mkdir -p /config/acme-certs/$LETSENCRYPT_DOMAIN
            if ! /config/acme.sh/acme.sh \
                    --install-cert -d $LETSENCRYPT_DOMAIN \
                    --key-file /config/acme-certs/$LETSENCRYPT_DOMAIN/key.pem  \
                    --fullchain-file /config/acme-certs/$LETSENCRYPT_DOMAIN/fullchain.pem ; then
                echo "Failed to install certificate."
                # this tries to get the user's attention and to spare the
                # authority's rate limit:
                sleep 15
                echo "Exiting."
                exit 1
            fi
        fi
    else
        # use self-signed certs
        if [[ -f /config/keys/cert.key && -f /config/keys/cert.crt ]]; then
            echo "using keys found in /config/keys"
        else
            echo "generating self-signed keys in /config/keys, you can replace these with your own keys if required"
            SUBJECT="/C=US/ST=TX/L=Austin/O=jitsi.org/OU=Jitsi Server/CN=*"
            openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -nodes -out /config/keys/cert.crt -keyout /config/keys/cert.key -subj "$SUBJECT"
        fi
    fi
fi

# Detect nameserver for Nginx, if not specified.
if [[ -z "$NGINX_RESOLVER" ]]; then
    IP_LIST=""

    # Parse IPs in /etc/resolv.conf, taking into account IPv6 addresses need to be
    # enclosed in square brackets for the Nginx config file.
    while read -r line; do
        if [[ $line =~ ^nameserver.* ]]; then
            IP=$(echo $line | cut -d" " -f2)
            COLONS=$(echo $IP | tr -dc ":" | awk '{ print length '})
            if [[ $COLONS -ge 2 ]]; then
                IP="[$IP]"
            fi
            if [[ ! "$IP_LIST" = "" ]]; then
                IP_LIST+=" "
            fi
            IP_LIST+="$IP"
        fi
    done < <(cat /etc/resolv.conf)

    export NGINX_RESOLVER=$IP_LIST
fi

echo "Using Nginx resolver: =$NGINX_RESOLVER="

# copy config files
tpl /defaults/nginx.conf > /config/nginx/nginx.conf

tpl /defaults/meet.conf > /config/nginx/meet.conf
if [[ -f /config/nginx/custom-meet.conf ]]; then
    cat /config/nginx/custom-meet.conf >> /config/nginx/meet.conf
fi

tpl /defaults/ssl.conf > /config/nginx/ssl.conf

tpl /defaults/default > /config/nginx/site-confs/default

tpl /defaults/system-config.js > /config/config.js
tpl /defaults/settings-config.js >> /config/config.js
if [[ -f /config/custom-config.js ]]; then
    cat /config/custom-config.js >> /config/config.js
fi

cp /defaults/interface_config.js /config/interface_config.js
if [[ -f /config/custom-interface_config.js ]]; then
    cat /config/custom-interface_config.js >> /config/interface_config.js
fi
```

EDIT: I ran the script manually to check what is causing the issue. Here is the log :

```html
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/config’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/config’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/nginx/tmp’: Permission denied
generating self-signed keys in /config/keys, you can replace these with your own keys if required
Generating a RSA private key
......................................................................+++++
................................................+++++
writing new private key to '/config/keys/cert.key'
req: Can't open "/config/keys/cert.key" for writing, No such file or directory
Using Nginx resolver: =127.0.0.53=
10-config: line 92: /config/nginx/nginx.conf: No such file or directory
10-config: line 94: /config/nginx/meet.conf: No such file or directory
10-config: line 99: /config/nginx/ssl.conf: No such file or directory
10-config: line 101: /config/nginx/site-confs/default: No such file or directory
10-config: line 103: /config/config.js: No such file or directory
10-config: line 104: /config/config.js: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/defaults/interface_config.js': No such file or directory
```

Comment: This seems like a networking/DNS issue - "W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'". On my machine, I was able to run this step without an issue.

Comment: My other projects work without issues on the same Ubuntu  22.04 gcp vm instance. Any fix that I should be attempting for this specifically ? I posted this on the jitsi community forums and they said too there is no issue in the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567404/docker-temporary-failure-resolving-deb-debian-org. Based on this post,  I tried specifying a dns server and restart docker but no change. Error is still there.

Comment: @Mureinik Based on your comment, I switched my operating system to Linux/Debian 10 and he error still persists. Could you let me know the OS you tested it on?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you can do to debug the issue.

**While logged into the container as root**: (`docker exec -it --user root  <containerID> bash`)

- ping the URLs, see if they get resolved
- see if the correct DNS is in use (maybe `cat /etc/resolv.conf` ??)
- install and try `dig` command (`dig @DNS-server-IP deb.debian.org`)
- try a little hack: edit `/etc/hosts` file, and enter `deb.debian.org` and `ftp.debian.org` IP addresses inside - that way your container should have no problems "resolving" the IP. After that, run apt-get commands again.

Now, I know this isn't an answer on how to solve the issue, but it could help debug the issue itself.

Comment: The docker container isn't getting built.  Regarding etc/hosts, I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, I'll just try it out.

Comment: I know it isn't getting build - I should have mentioned you should try the above things when the container is built, so without running apt-get commands that fail, or actually, without running that service. Changing hosts on your ubuntu host won't make a difference

Comment: Hi. I added deb.debian.org and ftp.debian.org insid etc/hosts file in Ubuntu. The error still persists.

Comment: Your ubuntu host probably resolves the debian urls just fine - it's the container that doesnt, thats why ypu should change the hosts file of the container itself

Comment: understood. will be tryin that now.

Comment: Upon doing 'cat /etc/resolv.conf ', I get nameserver 127.0.0.11 inside the running container which is the one where apt-get doesn work.

Comment: I'm inside the container hosts file. Could you give an example of deb.debian.org - IP addresses inside. I didn't understand he ip addresses part.

Comment: add `199.232.190.132 deb.debian.org` and `199.232.190.132 ftp.debian.org` to your hosts file

Comment: Also btw. Others are facing this issue as well. Found it on official docker discussions.https://forums.docker.com/t/temporary-failure-resolving-deb-debian-org-inside-all-docker-containers/134889/18

Comment: HI. Question has been updated. Could you please check.

Comment: Looks like that script exports an environment variable used by your container. Do you know what the output of `echo "Using Nginx resolver: =$NGINX_RESOLVER="` is? I'm thinking you could try to overwrite that variable, but in any case, this seems like a faulty script (bug) ...

Comment: Hi @GChuf. The owners of the open source repo gave me a cold shoulder saying that the script is fine and they are running it without issues. Looks like I'm stuck here debugging it myself. Regarding the nginx revolver , really do not know what that does, but build is supposed to install nginx and also read the etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Run the script manually, you'll see what the variable is like and then you can try to overwrite it ...

Comment: Sure. Can you let me know which environment variable that is that I need to debug ?

Comment: Hi again. Question updated with the log.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Restart docker daemon: `systemctl restart docker.service`
2. Specify DNS server for Docker daemon:
   Edit or create: `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
}
```

`systemctl restart docker.service`

3. Try setting you network to host:
   `docker build --network host`
4. Try adding `RUN chmod o+r /etc/resolv.conf` to your dockerfile.
5. Try adding `RUN echo -e "nameserver 8.8.8.8\nnameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf` and `RUN apt-get update` to your dockerfile.
6. Check if ip forwarding is enabled in your hosts `/etc/sysctl.conf`:
   `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`
7. Try setfacl: `setfacl -R -d -m o::rx /var/lib/docker` mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567404/docker-temporary-failure-resolving-deb-debian-org/66802006#66802006).

Comment: #net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 is how it is displayed inside /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: @Earthling
you need to uncomment 
`#net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`
then run sudo sysctl -p

Comment: Hi. I uncommented and did exactly as you told me to. The error still persists.

Comment: For 4. I get this : chmod: changing permissions of '/etc/resolv.conf': Read-only file system ------ failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c chmod o+r /etc/resolv.conf" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Comment: For 5. I get this : /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/resolv.conf: Read-only file system ------ failed to solve: process

Comment: HI. Question has been updated. Could you please check.

Answer (score 0):

Configure DNS for all containers, or add the following to the /etc/docker/daemon.json file to set it up.

```
 { "dns" : [ "114.114.114.114" , "8.8.8.8" ] }
```

This way the container DNS is automatically configured to 114.114.114.114 and 8.8.8.8 each time it is started. Use the following command to prove that it has taken effect.

```
 $ docker run -it cat etc/resolv.conf nameserver 114.114.114.114 nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: HI. Question has been updated. Could you please check.

Comment: Hi. Based on your instruction. I did edit daemon.json and save it and then enter the container and viewed resolv.conf. All I see three lines : search,nameserver 127.0.0.11, options edns trustad ndots:0. Seems the changes arent taking place

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. In the instructions, it was mentioned “DO NOT CLONE” but download the repo. It now works.
Never knew cloning a build rather than downloading the stable release would break things.

https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-docker/

I would like to thank everyone your time and help all his while.